# What practical experience does Pope Francis have with parenthood/fatherhood?

Tags: pope-francis, parenting

Recently I shared [Francis's tips for being a good father](https://aleteia.org/2015/03/20/pope-franciss-7-tips-for-being-a-good-father/), but my atheist friends do not consider Pope as authority as I do and are asking what is pope's expertise with parenthood?

By expertise I mean education or work with children, child psychologists, psychiatrists.

I read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Francis) but found nothing relevant. I also know about [Our Father](http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2018/03/10/our-father-reflections-on-lords-prayer-by-pope-francis.html) book but it will not be strong evidence for Pope's experience by my friends. What I did for now was to explain that author is irrelevant and one should reason about content, not about author.

Comment: He was a bouncer at a nightclub. That would give him some practical experience for parenting teenagers. 

Comment: I am not a papist but I think the answer lies in the fact that the imparting of Wisdom from the Word of God , while enhanced by personal experience in the realm of actualized faith, does not require it.  Atheists do not tend to give a lot of weight to the Scriptures unless backed by methods of human reason, including science, philosophy, or tradition.